# Error accessing Excel data table

Tags: c#, excel

i have to accessing data from excel worksheet, but i have problem while copy the data (from excel) to dataset

```
try
{
    string strPath = FileName;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " + "Data Source=" + strPath + "; " + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
    objConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + TableName + "] ", objConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
    objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
    objAdapter1.Dispose();//DEBUGGER SKIP FROM HERE
    objConn.Close();
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log your exception here.//
    return (DataTable)null;//AND THEN JUMP TO HERE
}
```

the problem is, while debugging, after line `objAdapter1.Fill(ds);` debugger skip the remaining line and of course the dataset is returning null, please help.

Comment: Inspect the exception.

Comment: Keep breakpoint at Dispose() line and check dataset is filling or not? and also check exception you are getting.

Comment: got 'Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll' while debug.
and i set breakpoint at Dispose(), the dataset is not filling, and return exception 'System.NullReferenceException' ( i think because the dataset is empty)

Comment: Bad exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extended properties in your connection string has to be in double quotes. Try the following line:

```
string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                           "Data Source=" + strPath + "; " + 
                           "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"";
```